# Using a tablet as a second monitor with Wayland

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, vnc, wayland

I use the following script to VNC into my computer using an old tablet to turn the tablet into a second monitor:

```bsh
xrandr --fb 3840x1080 --output eDP-1 --panning 3840x1080+0+0/3840x1080+0+0
sleep 3
xrandr --fb 3840x1080 --output eDP-1 --panning 1920x1080+0+0/3840x1080+0+0
x11vnc -clip 1920x1080+1921+0 -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -ncache 10 -ncache_cr
xrandr --fb 1920x1080
```

I don't think there is an equivalent of xrandr on (any major) Wayland (implementations), so I wonder if there is any other ways to use an old tablet as a second monitor. Sorry for the bad title, I just didn't know how else to phrase it.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Wayland on Debian, and xrandr is available, and currently lists XWAYLAND0 as an output to screen 0. But I couldn't create a new output (eDP-1), as it says "warning: output eDP-1 not found; ignoring". Perhaps it is related to Wayland, I'm not sure. I found [these steps](https://www.hitbits.net/2016/02/26/use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-monitor-for-linux-pc/) for setting up a vnc server (like yours, but with modeline !!!), though it also fails for me the exact same way: "warning: output VIRTUAL1 not found; ignoring".

Comment: Related question... unfortunately without answer either: https://www.reddit.com/r/wayland/comments/623los/distributed_multi_head_like_using_wayland_similar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of June 2021, only the [Sway](https://swaywm.org/) compositor appears to allow extending the desktop to another device, via VNC ([source](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2021-June/041846.html)). Indeed, users [have reported this to work fine](https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/k1zl41/thank_you_devs_free_ipad_repurposed_as_a_second/).

For instance Mutter (the default compositor for GNOME 3, in turn the default desktop environment in recent versions of Ubuntu) [can](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-40-Headless-Virtual) [create](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/1698) headless monitors (since version 40.0, released in March 2021), but [more work is required](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2021-May/041842.html) both to standardize the cross-platform API for screen casting of a virtual monitors, and to teach GNOME to record from one (so that it can be streamed over VNC).